# Make [mint] a synonym of [linux-mint]

Tags: support, tag-synonym-request

The tag [mint](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mint) is described as "Mint is a GNU/Linux desktop distribution." and has 39 questions.

The tag [linux-mint](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint) has a much more complete tag wiki and has 203 questions.

They mostly refer to the same thing; can we have them as tag synonyms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree;

```
updating post history, 43 rows affected
updating posts, 38 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 32 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [linux-mint] and [mint] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
2 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym mint -> linux-mint was approved!
```

.. and done!. Thanks for letting us know.